# Redux - Is using getState not elegant or inefficient?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Lets say I have a lot of entities in global store

- Apples
- Shops
- Juices

If I would like to have function getAppleJuicePrice, I can do it in 2-3 ways

1. Via parameters

   ```
   function getAppleJuicePrice(apples, juices) {
       return apples * juices; // Some computing
   }
   ```
2. Via getState, no parameters

   ```
   function getAppleJuicePrice() {
       return (dispatch, getState) => {
           const {apples, juices} = getState();

           return apples * juices; // Some computing
       }
   }
   ```
3. Via getState and parameters

   ```
   function getAppleJuicePrice(applesParam, juicesParam){
       return (dispatch, getState) => {
           const apples = applesParam || getState().apples;
           const juices = juicesParam || getState().juices;

           return apples * juices; // Some computing
       }
   }
   ```

*In case 2,3 I need to dispatch the function

Could you please give me your advise about

A) Functions 1,2,3 - Is it ok to do it in this way? Or some of them are better?

B) Architecture (I mean about fact that we are having a lot entities in the global store so we can even create functions which depend on them)

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly argue for example #1.

This function is pure, descriptive, and doesn't rely on outside knowledge.  Assuming you've already got access to state, it's almost *always* better to derive the values you're after rather than directly requesting state.

If that's not possible, then factor out the data retrieval to a second function, then pass your values into the first.  That way you've got a clear separation of concerns, your methods are easy to understand, you're not relying on side-effects (the presence of state values), and both methods should be easily testable.

Hell, you could go one further and refactor function 1 to be a generic utility for comparing/combining the prices of *whatever*, not just Apples and Juice.

```
const stateObject = getState() // At top of whatever scope

// Generic, no side-effects
function processPrice (x, y) {
  return x * y; // Whatever processing
}

// Specific, injected dependency on state
function getAppleJuicePrice (state) {
  const { apples, juice } = state;
  return processPrice(apples, juice);
}

// Explicit value assignment
const appleJuicePrice = getAppleJuicePrice(stateObject)
```

Just a quick comment on store architecture: Always aim to keep it as simple, flat, and data-related as possible.  Avoid compromising the data structure of your store simply for convenience of value computation.  Anything you can derive locally (and easily) you should do so.  The store isn't the place for complex value mutations.

(*preemptive *this is not a hard rule, just a guideline*)